# Perl script error Can't use an undefined value as a symbol reference at ./sendEvent.pl line 66

Tags: perl

Hello everyone i am new to perl scripting and  below is my perl script

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
```

I am getting the error
Can't use an undefined value as a symbol reference at ./sendEvent.pl line 66.

can anyone please tell me what is the issue?

Comment: `print $sock "$raw"` does not look right.

Comment: actually, that will work to print to a filehandle, assuming $sock is open.

Comment: After the last edit, the question does not make sense. For example: *"Can't use an undefined value as a symbol reference at ./sendEvent.pl line 66"* What is `sendEvent.pl` ? Please roll back to the previous version

Answer (score 4):

It seems as though your socket isn't connected, as that's where the undefined reference is being generated. 
Try ensuring that your socket is opened with the IO::Socket call...

```
$sock = IO::Socket::INET->new(PeerAddr => "$hostname",
                              PeerPort => "$port",
                              Proto    => 'tcp')
or die "can't connect to port $port on $hostname: $!";
```

or somesuch.

See where that gets you.  At the very least you'll know whether the socket connects correctly.

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick response!!!!!. Yes you are right  it might be the reason so i am restarting the server and checking if it works. Currently when i executed the script with your mentioned changes i got the below output    -          " can't connect to port 2010 on lgloz118: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. at ./sendEvent.pl line 31. " .  Will update once it works.....

Answer (score 2):

Attn: OP

Suggestion: use of hash simplifies typing and make code more readable

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use IO::Socket;
use Getopt::Long qw(GetOptions);
use Data::Dumper;

my %unit;
my @keys = qw(host port source name value part ptype module);
my @threshold = ("1000000");

# Defaults to avoid typing parameters
%unit = (
            host    => 'igloz118',
            port    => '2010',
            source  => 'APG_HEALTH',
            name    => 'RawValueCount',
            value   => '1000002',
            part    => 'APG',
            ptype   => 'APG-Frontend',
            module  => 'connecting',
            devtype => 'Host', 
            group   => 'group', 
            dname   => '.lss.emc.com'
        );

GetOptions(
            'host|h=s'      => \$unit{host},
            'port|p=s'      => \$unit{port},
            'source|s=s'    => \$unit{source},
            'name|n=s'      => \$unit{name},
            'value|v=s'     => \$unit{value},
            'part|p=s'      => \$unit{part},
            'ptype|pt=s'    => \$unit{ptype},
            'module|m=s'    => \$unit{module}
        ) or die "Usage: $0 --n NAME\n";

$unit{device} = $unit{host}.$unit{dname};

say '::: Parameters :::::';
printf "%-8s = %s\n", $_, $unit{$_} for @keys;
say '::::::::::::::::::::';

my $sock = IO::Socket::INET->new(
                                    PeerAddr => $unit{hostname},
                                    PeerPort => $unit{port},
                                    Proto    => 'tcp'
        ) or die "can't connect to port $unit{port} on $unit{host}: $!";;

@keys = qw/group variable value device devtype module part parttype name threshold source/;

for (my $i = 0; $i <=0 ; $i++) {
    my($timestamp,$raw);
    $timestamp = time;
    $unit{threshold} = $threshold[$i];
    $unit{variable}  = join '.', @unit{qw/source device part name/};
    $raw = join "\t", ( '+r', $timestamp, @unit{@keys} );

    print "$raw";
    print $sock "$raw";
}

close($sock);
```